# redirect https to http for domain.com page only by using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have purchased SSL certificate. And i have added https to all my web page using below script in htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Here i need to redirect from https to http for my homepage only.

Example:

```
https://www.domain.com to http://www.domian.com
```

Other pages should be redirect like below.

```
http://domain.com/login to https://www.domain.com/login

http://www.domian.com/register to https://www.domian.com/register
```

Note:
I need to append www to all my URLs for SEO purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.+` to not to match landing page in your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

However since you're also adding `www` I suggest following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# all pages except home page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!frontpageajax).+$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]

# landing page redirect https=>http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(frontpageajax/?)?$ http://www.%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Need one more help. I have written some ajax scripts in frontpageajax.php file. Currently this url contains https acess (https://domain.com/frontpageajax). So, from my domain page (http://domin.com), i couldn't able to get the response from ajax page. i need a solutions to redirect https to http for this page 'https://domain.com/frontpageajax' also along with my domain.com page. Can you please help? or suggest me to access ajax here...

Comment: Sorry I am traveling till Saturday and don't have my laptop with me. Please wait till Saturday or post a new question very help from other experts.